# React Native Style (top, left, bottom, right) behave different between Android and iOS

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, react-native

I encountered this issue where the UI display differently with the same code between Android and iOS.

[Android UI Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnVPq.png). You can only see half of the circle image in Android while you can see full circle image in iOS. Please see at the simulator on RNplay.

You can found my source code & re-simulate for this issue at 
https://rnplay.org/apps/q6LxiQ

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this issue is that RN iOS views default to `overflow: visible` while RN Android views only implement `overflow: hidden` due to how the native Android view system works. The behavior on Android is unlikely to change until Android itself changes.

To render consistently on both platforms, either set `overflow: 'hidden'` on your parent view or, to show the overflow, move the children out of the parent view and use an `onLayout` event on the parent view to get its position in order to calculate the desired position of the children, and absolutely position them.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I wrote a simple workaround from @ide answer.
For those looking for answer, you can have a look.
[link] (https://rnplay.org/apps/csbHfg)